# My JavaFx application works in Netbeans but not in eclipse..Why?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, javafx, javafx-8

This when I typed it into Netbeans it worked and I had the application show up on screen, but I prefer to use eclipse so when I copied and pasted it into Eclipse it did not work can someone help please. This is the error I got it did not compile.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
```

Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Access restriction: The method 'Application.launch(String[])' is not API (restriction on required library 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar')

```
at Tutorial1.main(Tutorial1.java:10)
... 11 more
```

Exception running application Tutorial1

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class Tutorial1 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    Button btn;

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Click Me Please");
        btn.setOnAction(e -> buttonClick());

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("The Click Me App");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public void buttonClick() 
    {
        if (btn.getText() == "Click Me Please") 
            {
            btn.setText("You Clicked Me");
            }
            else 
            {
            btn.setText("Click Me Please");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? Did it compile? Did it throw exceptions? What error messages did you get?

Comment: Tried your code on eclipse and worked fine, so as @James_D said , you should be more specific

Comment: this is the error i got

Comment: Just in case, I suppose your build path is ok, right? Check project properties -> Java build path -> libraries. You should have there the JRE, and when selecting it and clicking edit it should have version 8 in the execution environment. I remember having a similar error when switching from java 7 to 8. When I had that problem I resolved it in eclipse preferences -> installed JREs, deleting java8 & adding it again. But maybe I was just lucky :P

Answer (score -1):

1 - You do not need any plugin to use JavaFX in Eclise.

2 - Eclipse and Netbeans have different folder structure, when you create new "Java Project".

Best regards,

Comment: You only need that jar (and it only exists in that location) if you have a legacy (pre-Java 8) JDK. The OP is clearly using Java 8 (since the code includes lambda expressions).